# How to produce negative Nan?

Tags: swift, nan, infinity

I have a "creative" algorithm I'm working on, and there is a case where I need to return negative `Nan`.

```swift
extension Decimal { 
    func placement(
        between gains: Decimal,
        and losses: Decimal
    ) -> Decimal {
        if gains == losses { 
            return self > gains ? (1 / 0) : (-1 / 0)
        }
        return (self - losses) / (gains - losses)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `(-1 / 0)` produces Nan instead of `-Nan`.
I've accidentally created `-Nan` previously, unfortunately, I don't remember how it happened.

Comment: why would you need a "negative" NaN? If something is "NaN" why would if have a sign?

Comment: Why don't you directly write `-Double.nan` ?

Comment: `Decimal.nan < 0` is true, so NaN is negative! /s

Comment: I would also vote for using +/- Double.infinity that might make more sense but +/- Double.nan also would work as you can see in the following fiddle:

[link](https://swiftfiddle.com/lhndr4osrnc2lh3xtag4jsslxu)

Comment: @Sweeper That I very interesting since both Double.nan and Float.nan return false for `< 0` and all 3 of them return false for `> 0` and `== 0`. A bug? OP, it makes no sense to me to talk about negative NaN and that it will only lead to confusion further down the line to rely on such a thing in your code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, the result of comparison operation is defined in [IEEE NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). IEEE standard reserves several bit patterns for NaN, so you can distinguish all such NaNs if you can rely on the IEEE representation.

Comment: @OOPer Well then Decimal is not compliant with IEEE NaN but Double and Float are

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, True. The IEEE standard I referred defines binary floating point format (and operations), it does not include decimals.

Comment: @OOPer, while it doesn't explicitly include Decimals, Decimals appear to produce `Nan`.  `let new = Decimal(2); print(new / 0)`. @Joakim, there are a couple operations which I want to have no affect before becoming a csv representation.

Comment: @ScottyBlades, this is not a good place to discuss how Apple designed `Decimal`. One thing sure is it is designed to hold NaN and -NaN in some distinguishable representation.

Answer (score 1):

When something is literally "not a number", how can it have a meaningful sign?

And, from a practical perspective, how do you expect to distinguish "negative NaN" from "NaN"? `Decimal.nan == -Decimal.nan` is true, as well as `Decimal.nan < 0` and `-Decimal.nan < 0`

```
let n = Decimal.nan
let nn = -Decimal.nan

print (n < 0) // true
print (nn < 0) // true
print (nn < n) // false
print (n < nn) // false
print (n == nn) // true
```

Comment: Is is an answer or a question?

Comment: Upvoted because `-Decimal.nan` might be the closest we can get. Also, I appreciate you noting that Decimal.nan behaves different from Double.nan, for example: `print(Decimal.nan == Decimal.nan) // true, while \nprint(Double.nan == Double.nan) // false`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(-Double.nan) // produces -nan
print(-Decimal.nan) // produces Nan
```

I think Decimal might not track signed nan.  It doesn't distinguish between positive and negative nan but if it is negative nan, `isNan` will produce true.